# How To Return To The Main Activity After Destroying A SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android

My Activity

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    gv.gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    finish();
}
public void redirectHome(){

    onDestroy();
    Intent intent=new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My View's On Click.

```
if(gameover){
              //My Restart Button.
          if(x>(getWidth()*.39375) && x<(getWidth()*.625) &&
                  y>(getHeight()*.583333333) && y<(getHeight()*.654166667)){                  
              gameover=false;
              createSprites();
              destroyed=0;
          }
              //My Exit Button.
          if(x>(getWidth()*.39375) && x<(getWidth()*.625) &&
                  y>(getHeight()*.729166667) && y<(getHeight()*.791666667)){
              gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
              new PlayActivity().redirectHome();
          }

      }
```

My restart button works, but my exit button causes my app to crash pointing the error at 'Intent intent=new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);' and 'new PlayActivity().redirectHome();

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do nt must ot call "OnDestroy()" callback directly and also to call `finish()` in `onDestroy()` method.

In your case it would be better to change your code like to something like this:

```
protected void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
}
public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  gv.gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

}
public void redirectHome(){
 Intent intent=new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
}
```

Also one question: is this thing is really worked somehow? I'm asking this because `finish()` call in `onPause()` callback should close your activity even before it appears on the screen.

Anyway, check my code and comment about results)

EDIT: also you can't actually create instance of activity and call on of it's methods like `new PlayActivity().redirectHome();` so you need a `context` of `Аctivity` to perform start of new activity or finish this one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that because you can `onDestroy` the activity reference `PlayActivity.this` becomes invalid or null

You can use the application context instead of `PlayActivity.this` to and start your activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`